# Make URL as an anchor tag in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am getting an URL as a input which I want to assign it to an anchor tag.

Suppose the URL is

```
var url = "http://www.google.com";
```

I want to put this url like this

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
```

Comment: I am searching for solution. i failed to do this. thats why i aksed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement)

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "http://google.com";
a.textContent = a.href
```

Comment: Use `.textContent` or `.innerText` or `.appendChild(document.createTextNode(...))` instead of `.innerHTML=`.

Comment: @RobW I had it because I thought IE and FF didn't support textContent and innerText but that is not the case (any more). Thanks.

Comment: Old iE suck at `textContent` support. For compatibility, you can use `[document.textContent === null ? 'textContent' : 'innerText']` ([`document.textContent` has to be `null` when it's supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent#Description)).